# What happens with a callback if you app is killed by OS

Tags: android

Imagine your app is doing a network request for example, and a callback is called when the request is completed.

What happens if your app is killed by the OS to reclaim memory in the time that the request is happening and the callback isn't called yet.

Do users see an error on their device? is your callback canceled?

Comment: Why is this voted down?

Comment: That depends, if the proccess is terminated or just the Activity. If the process is terminated nothing else happens, if the activity then (it goes onDestroy process) the secondary thread continues and the callback is executed (that is a common source of Exceptions)

Comment: Android does not kill an activity if it needs memory. What it does is that it kills the whole process that the activity is running in

Comment: It can kill activities whitin the same application for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do users see an error on their device?

Not usually.

> is your callback canceled?

Yes, insofar as your entire process is terminated.

Comment: yeah the process is terminated, but the callback is still in the looper queue i think. Do you got any source to confirm this?

Comment: @PrisonMike: "but the callback is still in the looper queue i think" -- the only thing that I know of that qualifies as "the looper queue" consists of objects in your process. When your process is terminated, those objects are gone, along with the callback object and everything else in that process. The only things that survive process termination are things that are outside of your process. So, for example, where you see a `PendingIntent` used, that is for event stuff (e.g., `AlarmManager`) that can survive process termination.

Comment: ok seems like a good answer to me, i'll accept it in a few min (i have to wait a few minutes)